# Oracle Cloud Infrastructure - Replicate Vault Across Regions

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have created a vault/key under a compartment. 
As vault service is a regional service it is only available under the region I created it.
Even if tenancy subscribes to multiple region the compartment shows up but still Vault is not available for that region. Is there a way we could replicate Vault / Key /secrets while tenancy subscribes to multiple regions .

Comment: At the moment the only option I know of is to [import the keys](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/KeyManagement/Tasks/importingkeys.htm) into the different regions yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself, but you could try this approach and see if the following steps will work for you:

Step 1. Use the [BackupKey/BackupVault](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/key/release/Key/BackupKey) API (from Vault Service) in the SOURCE region to create the relevant key/vault encrypted file(s).

Step 2. Use the [CopyOBject](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/CopyObject) API (from Object Storage Service) to copy the file(s) created in Step 1 from your SOURCE region to all DESTINATION regions.

Step 3. Use the [RestoreKey/RestoreVault](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/key/release/methods/RestoreKeyFromObjectStore) API (from Vault Service) to restore the key/vault in the DESTINATION regions. See